# Regular Expressions in Calculator

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I'm working with some code that uses regular expressions. It is for a Javascript calculator. All scenarios work, except for:

```
-number X number
```

The negative is throwing everything off and I've tracked it down to this function. Normally, it returns exactly what you see on the calculator screen. However, when the negative is introduced, it returns null. I'm not great with regex so am hoping someone can make sense of this? How would I allow for the negative as well?

```
function(){
 return expr.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?[-+*/]\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?$/);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your regular expression:

```
/^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?[-+*/]\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?$/
```

Let's break it apart:

- ^ String starts with...
- \d{1,} // One or more digits
- (.\d{1,})?  // followed by a potential fraction (dot and then more digits)
- [-+*/] // followed by an operator
- \d{1,} // followed by one or more digits
- (.\d{1,})? // followed by a potential fraction (dot and then more digits)
- $ // string ends

So yes, your regular expression says: "The string must start with a digit". Not with a minus. If you add `-?` this would optionally (`?`) allow a minus (`-`). You'd need to insert that part after "String starts with" and before the first sequence of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Seems as though you simply need to allow your regex to detect the potential negative sign.  In this particular scenario (perhaps not comprehensive enough for all occasions), lead your calculation with `-?` ("hyphen, maybe").  Your resultant regex would appear as:

`^-?\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?[-+*/]\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?$`

Consider the following from a NodeJS terminal:

```
> "3+2".match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?[-+*/]\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?$/);
[ '3+2',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: '3+2' ]
> "-3+2".match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?[-+*/]\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?$/);
null
> "-3+2".match(/^-?\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?[-+*/]\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?$/);
[ '-3+2',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: '-3+2' ]
```

The first attempt is using a simple "3+2" calculation with your provided code, which parses correctly.  The second attempt applies the same regex to "-3+2" and returns `null` (as you were experiencing).  Finally, repeating the same calculation against the regex alterations I suggest once again results in valid output.